# Creating a dictionary from list of lists using only one for loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop, nested-lists

I came across this question in a test. There are two parts to this question:

Part i:

Given a list of flavors, eg. ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'], write a function that returns a dictionary of the number of each flavor respectively.

My solution:

```
flavors = ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C']

def count_flavors(l):
    dict_flavors={}
    for i in l:
        dict_flavors[i] = l.count(i)
    return dict_flavors

print(count_flavors(flavors))
```

Part ii:

Using not more than ONE for loop write a function that accepts a list of lists of flavors eg. [['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C']] and returns a dictionary for the total number of each flavor. You must include the function that you defined in part one in this solution.
(To clarify, essentially there should only be two for loops; one from part one and one from part two)

So far my solution is the following:

```
batches = [['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'], ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B' ,'B','B','C'], ['A','B','C','C']]

def batch_count(b):
    batch_dict = []
    result = {}
    for j in b:
        batch_dict.append(count_flavors(j))
    print(batch_dict)
    for i in batch_dict:
        for k in i.keys():
            result[k] = result.get(k,0) + i[k]
    return result

print('batch count 1:' + str(batch_count(batches)))
```

I am struggling to find a solution that only uses one for loop for this part. I am aware that there are modules that exist for this sort of thing like `collections.Counter()`. Is a naive solution that does not include any modules possible for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I have updated my answer as per your requirements. Let me know how it goes for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the **best naive** solution **which I can think of** in order to achieve what you want

**Benefits of using the solution**

> 1. No need to create extra variable like `batch_dict = []`, which takes unnecessary space in your system
> 2. No need to carry out multiple computations using different methods, like you did above using `count_flavors()`
> 3. Straight forward and easy to understand

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
batches = [['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'], ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B' ,'B','B','C'], ['A','B','C','C']]

def batch_count(b):
    result = {} # for storing final count results
    # two loops are required to get into the arrays of array, not other option is there
    for items in b:
        # Getting the nested array item here
        for item in items:
            # final computation, if the item is there in the result dict, then increment
            # else simply assign 1 to the item as a key which eventually gives you the total number
            # of counts of each item throughout the batches array items
            if item in result:
                result[item] += 1
            else:
                result[item] = 1
    return result

print('batch count 1:' + str(batch_count(batches)))

# OUTPUT
# >>> batch count 1:{'A': 7, 'C': 7, 'B': 10}
```

Feel free to test this out for some other batches too, and let me know. This is by far the naive solution which is possible to give out what you want to achieve. Keep learning :)

**ANOTHER SOLUTION [MAKING USE OF FIRST METHOD COUNT_FLAVORS]**

Hey, if you really want to use the first method, then there is a work around, but you need to compromise with one thing now, that is `Counter` has to be imported, but I assure you, it will be as simple as that, and will give you straight forward answer

> Your `count_flavors` works fine, so we take the `count_falvors()` as is.
> We will be making changes to the `batch_count` method now

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
from collections import Counter

# Taking your method as is, to get the dictionary which counts
# the items occurence from your array
def count_flavors(l):
    dict_flavors={}
    for i in l:
        dict_flavors[i] = l.count(i)
    return dict_flavors


# This method will do your stuffs
def batch_count(b):
   result = {} #this will be used to return the final result
   # now just one loop, since we will passing the array 
   # to our method for computation count_flavors()
   for items in b:  # this will give out single array
        '''
        now we will call your count_flavor method
        we will use Counter() to merge the dictionary data
        coming from the count_flavor and then add it to the result
        Counter() keep track of same item, if present in multiple
        dict, ADDS +1 to the same item, doesn't duplicate value
        Hence counter required
        '''
        if len(result) != 0:
            # if the result is not empty, then result = result + data
            result += Counter(count_flavors(items)) # no more extra for loop
        else:
            # else first fill the data by assigning it
            result = Counter(count_flavors(items))
   # this will give out the output in {}
   # else the output will come in Counter({}) format
   return dict(result)
   
# our test array of arrays
batches = [['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'], ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B' ,'B','B','C'], ['A','B','C','C']]

print('batch count 1:' + str(batch_count(batches)))

# OUTPUT
# >>> batch count 1:{'A': 7, 'B': 10, 'C': 7}
```

In this way you achieve the output with the usage of your `count_flavors()` method too, that too with no multiple loops in the `batch_count()`. Hope that will give you more clarity :). If this works out for you, you may accept the answer, for the the people who will come looking for answer to this question :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I agree that this is a more straightforward solution and there must be more than one 'for' loop. For the sake of the question, I am still looking for how I can modify your solution such that it fulfills the requirement to utilize the function defined in part i... Thanks for the input nonetheless! :)

Comment: Hey @kwekie, no problem. I have updated my answer, and in the updated one that is, **ANOTHER SOLUTION [MAKING USE OF FIRST METHOD COUNT_FLAVORS]**, we make use of the method which you wanted with no extra loops. Let me know if that works for you :)

Comment: Hey @Alok I wasn't aware that Counter objects could be added to each other using ```+=```, I was looking for a way to implement the += method to two dict objects but the operation is unsupported...  I guess your final solution seems the closest to the question requirements, thanks once again! :D

Comment: I am really glad, that we got a chance to learn something from each other :) All the best

Answer (score 1):

The first function can become much faster by modifying your approach in this way:

```
def count_flavors(lst):
    dict_flavors = {}
    for item in lst:
        if item in dict_flavors:
            dict_flavors[item] += 1
        else:
            dict_flavors[item] = 1
    return dict_flavors
```

You could also use `Counter` to simplify your code:

```
from collections import Counter

def count_flavors(lst):
    return dict(Counter(lst))
```

The second function can use `itertools.chain`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

def batch_count(b):
    return dict(Counter(chain(*b)))
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! Could you please explain why your solution for part i would be faster? Thanks

Comment: @kwekie let's say you have a list with the same element repeated 1000 times. In your solution you *count* that element for 1000 times. In other words you scan the entire list 1000 times. Instead, you could do it just once. Using a `count` is like using a for loop through all the elements of the list. So in your case you would have a for loop within another for loop.